# How to avoid re-layout of views when calling setSystemUiVisibility()?

Tags: android

when I call setSystemUiVisibility() to show/hide SystemUi,
onLayout() of view is called.

I tried the same code as in "https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/immersive".

is it possible to avoid re-layout of views when calling setSystemUiVisibility()?

I think that re-layout is redundant because the layout of view is not changed if these flags are set.
View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE,
View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION,
View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN

Comment: [answering my own question]
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS);
if i add this flag to the window, re-layout doesn't happen when setSystemUiVisibility() is called.

Comment: but with this flag, app bar is overlaid with status bar.
i'm looking for a way to avoid the overlay.